# Why would a square matrix transform?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, chirality

Why would a square matrix of spinless fields $\Lambda$ transform under symmetries?

Given:
$$\delta \psi_L = i \epsilon_L^aT_a\psi_L$$
and $$\delta \psi_R = i \epsilon_R^aT_a\psi_R$$

Comment: Please define the notation used in your post, and clarify whether "spinless field" is supposed to mean *Lorentz scalar*.

Comment: Done @ACuriousMind

Comment: You have not *defined* any notation. Are the $T_a$ generators? If yes, of which group? The $\epsilon$ are infinitesimal parameters? How is $\Sigma$ related to the $\psi_{L/R}$? The $\psi_{L/R}$ are the chiral Weyl spinor components of a full Dirac spinor?

Comment: $T_a$ of generator (rotation). Yes $\epsilon$ is an infinitesimal parameter. $\Sigma$ is matrix of spinless fields and $\psi's$ describe the left and right handedness of composite spinor $\psi$. @ACuriousMind

Comment: I don't understand why you have written anything about the $\psi$ here at all if it is not related to the $\Sigma$. You can't just say "$\Sigma$ is a matrix of spinless fields", you have to say (or know) in which representation of the chiral symmetry $\mathrm{SU}(2)_L \times \mathrm{SU}(2)_R$ the component fields transform. (Spinless doesn't say anything about this. The Higgs is a Lorentz scalar, yet it transforms non-trivally under the electroweak $\mathrm{SU}(2)_L$.) I suspect the transformation of $\Sigma$ is a *definition* here. What reference is this from, anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we are looking at here is a $\sigma$-model that exemplifies strong chiral symmetry breaking. The theory first only contains a massless Dirac spinor $\psi$, which is *assumed* to transform in the fundamental representation<sup>1</sup> of a global $\mathrm{SU}(2)_\text{iso}$ symmetry. The Lagrangian contains only the kinetic term:

$$ L[\psi] = \mathrm{i} \bar\psi \gamma^\mu\partial_\mu \psi $$

Now, this Lagrangian has an "accidental" larger symmetry, since it is also invariant under chiral transformations (as may be checked). The full global symmetry is $\mathrm{SU}(2)_L \times \mathrm{SU}(2)_R$, which contains the isospin as the diagonal subgroup where $\epsilon_R = \epsilon_L$.

Now, such a theory cannot naively acquire mass - the symmetry forbids the mass terms, and we would rather not break the symmetry explicitly in this model. Hence, the idea is to try and find some (Lorentz scalar) field $\Sigma$ which could acquire a vacuum expectation value and hence break the symmetry spontaneously, granting masses to the $\psi$.<sup>2</sup>

It turns out that the Lagrangian

$$ L[\psi,\Sigma] = \mathrm{i} \bar\psi \gamma^\mu\partial_\mu \psi - g (\bar\psi_L \Sigma \psi_R + \bar\psi_R \Sigma^\dagger \psi_L) $$

is invariant under the full symmetry group if we take $\Sigma$ to transform in the adjoint representation of $\mathrm{SU}(2)_\text{iso}$. *This is a definition - in principle, we are free to take any other transformation behaviour of $\Sigma$!* The adjoint representation is the representation of a Lie group upon its own algebra induced by the Lie bracket/commutator. That is, we take $\Sigma$ to be $\mathfrak{su}(2)$-valued, and $T^a \in \mathfrak{su}(2)_\text{iso}$ acts upon $\Sigma$ as

$$ \mathrm{ad}(T^a)(\Sigma) := [T^a,\Sigma] = T^a\Sigma - \Sigma T^a$$

Since the isospin (with $\epsilon_R = \epsilon_L$) is diagonal in the full symmetry group, this naturally induces the action of the full symmetry as

$$ \mathrm{ad}(\epsilon_LT^a_L,\epsilon_RT^b_R)(\Sigma) = \epsilon_L T_L^a\Sigma - \epsilon_R \Sigma T_R^a $$

with integrated version

$$ \Sigma \mapsto U_L \Sigma U_R^\dagger \quad \text{where} \quad (U_L,U_R) \in \mathrm{SU}(2)_L \times \mathrm{SU}(2)_R $$

One may check that the Lagrangian is indeed invariant under this, and that it stays invariant if we allow $\Sigma$ to be an element of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ plus a multiple $\sigma$ of the identity, i.e.

$$ \Sigma = \sigma \mathrm{Id}_2 + \mathrm{i}\pi_a\sigma^a$$

where the $\sigma^a$ are the Pauli matrices that generate $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>The fundamental representation of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is a *doublet*, i.e. two-dimensional, hence we could write $\psi = \left(\begin{matrix}p \\ n\end{matrix}\right)$, where $p$ and $n$ are both full Dirac spinors.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup>The $\psi$-doublet is thought to be a doublet containing proton and neutron, and the $\Sigma$ is the pion field mediating the strong force in the low-energy regime.</sup>

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics: The Lagrangian is invariant because under a transformation $(U_L,U_R) \in \mathrm{SU}(2)_L \times \mathrm{SU}(2)_R$, we have $\psi_{R/L} \mapsto U_{R/L}\psi_{R/L}$, $\bar\psi_{R/L} \mapsto \bar\psi_{R/L}U^\dagger_{R/L}$ and $\Sigma \mapsto U_L \Sigma U_R^\dagger$. (This is (2.6.9) in your pdf) Their (2.6.12) is just the explicit form of this, showing that the decomposition into the $\sigma$ and the $\pi$ fields is a "good" decomposition.

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics: Yes, if you take the transformations in my post and calculate $\delta\Sigma$, you will find exactly what is in (2.6.12) in your pdf.

Comment: @PhilosophicalPhysics: What do you mean, "prove these decompositions"? What more than "a $\Sigma$ of that form works" do you want?

Comment: @PhilosopicalPhysics: The transformations in my first comment show the invariance of the Lagrangian if plugged into it. If you take them and Taylor expand them to first order, i.e $\Sigma \mapsto \Sigma + \delta\Sigma$, you recover the expressions from your pdf. I fear I don't really understand what you want to know.